# Inequality (Hölder?)

Tags: inequality

How to prove the inequality
$$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,j}\right)^n\leq\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j}^n $$
for non-negative $a_{i,j}$ ?
(Maybe for reals?)

It was said to me, that it is Hölder's inequality, but I found something with integrals stated as Hölder, or I also found the form $$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sqrt[m]{\prod_{i=1}^m a_{i,j}}\right)^m\le\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{i,j} $$ but don't know, how to use it...

Thx for any advice/help.

Comment: Yes, Hölder. A sum is an integral with respect to a counting measure, so it fits in the integral framework. One could of course - with basically the same proof - prove Hölder's inequality especially for sums. Then you need to generalise it from two factors to arbitrarily many.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively easy to conclude from the Hölder inequality for sequences or functions the inequality
$$
\|a⋅b\|_r\le \|a\|_p⋅\|b\|_q
$$
for $\frac1p+\frac1q=\frac1r$ and the product on the left is point-wise. Applying this recursively gives
$$
\|a_1⋅a_2 \cdots a_n\|_1\le \|a_1\|_{q_1}⋅\|a_2\|_{q_2}⋯\|a_n\|_{q_n}
$$
under the assumption 
$$
1=\frac1{q_1}+\frac1{q_2}+⋯+\frac1{q_n}
$$
Yours is the special case with $q_k=n$. That the sums go to $n$ is an unnecessary coincidence.